# Phone call notification on Mac opens FaceTime app, interrupting work

Tags: macos, notifications, facetime

I wanted to get notifications on my computer for phone calls, so I set up my Macbook to make and receive phone calls.

When I receive a phone call, FaceTime opens and then the notification appears.

The problem is that in doing so, FaceTime briefly shows up as the current application in the menu bar (although no full window opens, I believe) and I lose focus of my current application for a second or two—interrupting my typing or other activity. Is there a way to eliminate this disruption?

If it's any help, I'm not interested in answering or making the calls on my Mac. I just want a way to get the notification. I've looked into ways of getting ios notifications on mac, but all of the apps I've found appear to be unavailable on the App Store or cost money.